# Recreate folders structure

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, organizer-software

I am using program called "Advanced File Organizer" to catalog my folders, It just create a structure copy of folders with names, sizes and types. That is great, But I want to recreate this structure into real folders and files, for sure I don't want real content or real files I just want the structure.
The program could export structure to xml and xls
Is there any solution to create real structure from exported files?

Comment: Can you show us an excerpt of your XML? Maybe 20-30 lines. Excel+VBA+Shell command can do what you want. Just give me a [sneak peak at your XML](http://ge.tt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify whether this catalog gathers information from a single drive or folder, or whether it's from multiple drives or network shares.

If your information is from a single drive or folder, Windows does come with a command that can mirror a folder structure. Open up a command prompt and type:

```
xcopy <original drive/folder> <new location (drive  or folder)> /T /E
```

Example 1: `xcopy c:\users\joeuser d:\ /T /E`

Example 2: `xcopy c:\users\joeuser c:\backup /T /E`

You can get more information by typing `xcopy /?`.